# Remove milliSeconds from String in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate

Trying to remove milli seconds from String(date)

```
NSString *dateString = @"2016-05-16 13:17:34.674194";
 NSDateFormatter* formater = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
 [formater setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"];
 NSDate *date = [formater dateFromString:dateString];
 NSLog(@"%@",[formater stringFromDate:date]);
```

and i'm getting null

i'm expecting o/p something like (with out milli seconds)

"06/05/2016 13:17:34"

Please suggest...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Copy and paste  this Code working Perfectly

```
NSString *dateString = @" ";
NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter1 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
dateFormatter1.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS";
NSDate *yourDate = [dateFormatter1 dateFromString:dateString];
dateFormatter1.dateFormat = @"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss";
NSLog(@"%@",[dateFormatter1 stringFromDate:yourDate]);
```

Here is Output

```
2016-05-16 16:43:53.639 StackLearn[6376:151614] 16/05/2016 13:17:34
```

> Rule of Date formatter is you must set date format same like your string while you are getting date from string , if mismatch then you will get null

Comment: its working buddy.. and your comment is valuable in your answer.

Comment: This code shows how to do the conversion, but note that for production code, you should really set up properties that hold your input date formatter and output date formatter, and then reuse them each time. (Creating and configuring a date formatter is fairly expensive, so you want to do it once for each unique date formatter.)

Answer (score 1):

try this:-

```
NSString *dateString = @"2016-05-16 13:17:34.674194";
NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SS";     
NSDate *yourDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss";
NSLog(@"%@",[dateFormatter stringFromDate:yourDate]);
```

Comment: Your formatter is still wrong. The initial format string should be `@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSS"`. The upper-case "S"es are for fractions of a second. Lower-case "s"s give you whole seconds.

Answer (score 0):

working Perfect

```
NSString *dateString = @" ";
NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter1 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
dateFormatter1.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS";
NSDate *yourDate = [dateFormatter1 dateFromString:dateString];
dateFormatter1.dateFormat = @"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss";
NSLog(@"%@",[dateFormatter1 stringFromDate:yourDate]);
```